# Dynamic focus management [ AIR / AS3 ]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, focus

I've run into a situation with a project I'm working on and I'm hoping to get some insight on how I might go about tackling it. Basically I am writing an AIR/AS3 app that allows the user to move focus around using the arrow keys on the keyboard. The problem I am trying to over come is that the clips are dynamically placed so I have no idea ahead of time what their position will be relative to each other. In addition to that, all of the clips have different shapes and sizes, so part of the weirdness is that some clips would occupy multiple columns, or multiple rows if you were laying out their positions on a grid for example.

So, the goal would be to have some logic that evaluates all of the clips sizes and/or positions and creates some form of map that allows clips to know who their nearest neighbor is when pressing right, left, up or down. The question is, what is the best approach for tackling something like this? I ultimately need it to feel very natural when moving around, and be far more intelligent then a tab-index list for example.

If I haven't provided enough information, please let me know and I can share additional details as needed. Just didn't want to go all crazy trying to explain things to start with.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Using the reference image, assume block "D" has focus. Using the logic @Pier's provided below, if I was to press "UP", would it know to go to block "A", or would it go to block "B" because it's distance and angle are less? In this case I think the user would expect it to go to block "A", but I'm thinking the code would evaluate to block "B" if I understand it correctly.

Comment: and what is wrong with tab index list? YOU have control over it and YOU set it up so the intelligence ultimately comes from you:) I would use Pier's answer and reapply tab indexes based on the distance (and this is for tabbing). Anyway flash handles pretty good the arrow keys focus change IMO.

Comment: Hmmm, guess I can't hit ENTER for a new line in comments without submitting.....Anyways, what's wrong with a tab-index list is that the user is not tabbing. A tab-index list implies that a certain order will be followed. In this case, the user has the ability to move around freely based on the clips position to each other using the arrow keys, and in no predefined order or direction. So I'm not sure how an ordered list of any type would be helpful here. However, as you suggested, I will be looking at @Pier 's solution today to see if this solves my issue and will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay following up here, but I ended up solving my issue by dynamically generating a grid map of all the clips positions which then allowed me to scan in various directions to find the next clip getting focus. Here is an output based on the example picture I provided originally:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

I've had to adjust the grid size to balance the performance vs. fidelity, but it seems to be working great in the various scenarios I needed it.

Thanks again for the help @Pier. Although I didn't end up using the ray casting approach, it was very informative learning about it. I could see how in a game for example that could be super powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the distance and relative angle between two clips is easy (simple trigonometry). here are the function to calculate distance and angle between 2 x,y positions.

```
    function angle(x1,y1,x2,y2):Number{
        return radToDeg(Math.atan2((y2 - y1),(x2 - x1)));
    }

    function radToDeg(angle:Number):Number{
        // to convert radians to degrees
        return angle * 180 / Math.PI;
    }

    function distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):Number{
        var dx:Number = x1 - x2;
        var dy:Number = y1 - y2;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
```

Knowing that, simply look what arrow the user has pressed. Then look the angles and distances of the other clips, and look how many clips there are in current direction (eg: what clips have an angle offset less than +-45 degrees), then look which one is closer, then change focus if there is any clip that meets the conditions.

I presume you won't have hundreds of clips placed on the stage, because in that case you should only calculate the angles for the closest clips.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try to implement this example today and see if it helps resolve my issue. In the meantime, I have added an image to the original post and added a possible scenario below it to help describe the issue. Please let me know if you feel this is still the correct solution to overcome the problem. I will also report back once I get you example code in place where I can test it. Thanks!

Comment: My method should work in the diagram you have provided, or at least be a starting point to a more refined solution. In the image, what should happen when you are on A and press down?

Comment: Well, that's a great question. I would think that if I started on A, pressing DOWN would take me to C. However, expanding on my original example if I started on D, pressed UP and went to A, then it feels natural that if I pressed DOWN I would go back to D. In addition to that scenario, if I was on F and pressed LEFT, would I go to C or D? Seems natural to go to C, but it seems D would evaluate as a far closer option. So, this is a bit of the weirdness I am trying to work out....hopefully in a very elegant and dynamic way.

Comment: Well then my solution will not work for you. For that to work the way you want it, you should use a 2d ray cast system and see what objects cross with the ray. Also you will need to implement some form of history. http://rocketmandevelopment.com/blog/as3-2d-ray-casting-for-collision-detection/

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking the time to comment. I'll check out the link and we'll see if that points me in the right direction.